# ¿como comunicar archivos en Python?

Tags: python

disculpen tengo el siguiente problema, resulta que intento comunicar unos archivos entre si pero no lo logro por la estructura en la que este esta o eso pienso ya que ya he comunicado algunos y me funciona perfecto, a continuación un ejemplo:

Importación que me funciona
archivo google.py
la estructura es una función

```
def googlemaps():
```

Así lo importo en el otro archivo

```
from googlemaps import googlemaps

self.button1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.frame_button, image=self.boton20, text="", width=120, height=120, command=googlemaps,
                                        corner_radius=25, border_color="#F1EBE9", fg_color="gray40", hover_color="#F1EBE9")
```

Estos funcionan genial porque llamo la función y la ejecuto desde el otro archivo por medio de un botón. Pero el que me genera problema es este:

```
class LoginIDVision(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args):
        super().__init__(master, *args)
        self.usuarioVerify = ''
        self.contrasenaVerify = ''
        self.usuarioVerify = StringVar()
        self.contrasenaVerify = StringVar()
        self.usuarioEntry = ''
        self.contrasenaEntry = ''
        self.inicio_sesion()


    
    def inicio_sesion(self):
```

en este archivo no me funciona ya que no se como importarla correctamente y que funcione, alguien que tal vez me pueda ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score -1):

lo que entiendo es que tienes dos archivos, uno con el tema de googlemaps y el otro con la clase LoginIDVision. y quieres traer lo de googlemaps a al archivo que contiene la clase.

Comment: Tu respuesta suena mas a un comentario, por favor utilizar los comentarios si tienes dudas sobre la pregunta